# Создать constexpr array/vector из вызовов шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, constexpr

Нужна довольно странная вещь. Имеются вызовы некой шаблонной функции

```
foo<1>();
foo<2>();
foo<5>();
```

Имея только эти вызовы, нужно каким-то образом получить вектор/массив/дерево/что угодно, что будет хранить

```
{1, 2, 5}
```

Подвох в том, что вектор/дерево/массив, хранящий в себе `{1, 2, 5}` должен быть создан **до вызовов** шаблонной функции. Иными словами, имея только саму декларацию этих вызовов(они могут быть не вызваны вовсе), нужно получить контейнер.

Это возможно? И если возможно, как?

UPD: в целом, можно и не контейнер получить, а например другую функцию вида

```
bar<1, 2, 5>();
```

Comment: Интересная задача, но я не понимаю, зачем это нужно...

Comment: Где-то глубоко в коде программы может быть строка, извлекающая некоторый параметр из конфига. Эта строка ещё не была достигнута, но значения в конфиге нет уже сейчас. Программа должна вылетать сразу после запуска, если ей не хватает какого-то параметра из конфига. Но при обычных условиях, она поймёт, что параметра в конфиге не хватает только при попытке извлечения. Это проблема - программа вылетит посреди работы

Comment: Перечислять все обязательные параметры при инициализации парсера конфига - лень. Тем более, все необходимые параметры уже были перечислены - при декларации каждого извлечения из конфига по ключу

Comment: ИМХО, шаблоны Вам не помогут. Я бы добавил к парсеру конфига метод, который регистировал бы потребителей. Потребители возвращают парсеру список опций с укаанием обязательности либо дефолтных значений. Более подробно нужно смотреть по задаче.

Comment: Проводите извлечение параметров сразу после запуску.

Comment: Мы на работе грузим конфиг именно так, как вы описываете - это выглядит как `getConfig<type, "foo.bar">()`, и отлично работает. Но не опенсурс, к сожалению.

Answer (score 3):

Этот трюк существует в двух вариантах:

1. Массив заполняется сразу при запуске программы. Туда попадают элементы из всех единиц трансляции. Такой список, очевидно, не может `constexpr`, потому что каждая единица трансляции компилируется независимо.
2. Массив заполняется во время компиляции. Тут он спокойно может быть `constexpr`, но видит элементы только из текущей единицы трансляции, и все элементы должны быть зарегистрированы выше по тексту.

Вариант (1) в целом уже написан в другом ответе, но приведу немного другое исполнение, которое мне больше нравится - без замены функции на шаблонную переменную с `operator()` и т.п.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl
{
    std::set<int> &MutRegistry()
    {
        // Переменная обязательно внутри функции, чтобы избежать static init order fiasco.
        static std::set<int> ret;
        return ret;
    }

    template <int N>
    static const auto register_value = []{
        MutRegistry().insert(N);
        return nullptr;
    }();
}

const std::set<int> &Registry()
{
    return impl::MutRegistry();
}

template <int N>
void foo()
{
    (void)std::integral_constant<const std::nullptr_t *, &impl::register_value<N>>{};
}

int main()
{
    for (int x : Registry())
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 10, 20

    foo<10>();
    foo<20>();
}
```

Вариант (2) пишется сильно сложнее, нужно использовать stateful metaprogramming.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct tag {using type = T;};

template <auto V>
struct value_tag {static constexpr auto value = V;};

template <typename...>
struct type_list {};

namespace StatefulList
{
    namespace // Hopefully guard against ODR violations?
    {
        namespace impl
        {
            template <typename Name, std::size_t Index>
            struct ElemReader
            {
                #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
                #pragma GCC diagnostic push
                #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
                #endif
                friend constexpr auto adl_ListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>);
                #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
                #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
                #endif
            };

            template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Value>
            struct ElemWriter
            {
                friend constexpr auto adl_ListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>)
                {
                    return tag<Value>{};
                }
            };

            [[maybe_unused]] constexpr void adl_ListElem() {} // A dummy ADL target.

            template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique, typename = void>
            struct CalcSize : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Index> {};

            template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique>
            struct CalcSize<Name, Index, Unique, decltype(void(adl_ListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>{})))> : CalcSize<Name, Index + 1, Unique> {};

            template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique>
            using ReadElem = typename decltype(adl_ListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>{}))::type;

            template <typename Name, typename I, typename Unique>
            struct ReadElemList {};
            template <typename Name, std::size_t ...I, typename Unique>
            struct ReadElemList<Name, std::index_sequence<I...>, Unique> {using type = type_list<ReadElem<Name, I, Unique>...>;};
        }

        struct DefaultUnique {};

        template <typename T>
        struct DefaultPushBackUnique {};

        // Calculates the current list size.
        template <typename Name, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
        [[maybe_unused]] inline constexpr std::size_t size = impl::CalcSize<Name, 0, Unique>::value;

        // Touch this type to append `Value` to the list.
        template <typename Name, typename Value, typename Unique = DefaultPushBackUnique<Value>>
        using PushBack = impl::ElemWriter<Name, size<Name, Unique>, Value>;

        // Returns the type previously passed to `WriteState`, or causes a SFINAE error.
        template <typename Name, std::size_t I, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
        using Elem = impl::ReadElem<Name, I, Unique>;

        // Returns the list elements as `Meta::TypeList<...>`.
        template <typename Name, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
        using Elems = typename impl::ReadElemList<Name, std::make_index_sequence<size<Name, Unique>>, Unique>::type;
    }
}

struct FooList {};

namespace // Guard against ODR violations?
{
    template <typename Unique = void>
    consteval auto FooElems()
    {
        return []<typename ...P>(type_list<P...>){
            return std::array<int, StatefulList::size<FooList, Unique>>{
                P::value...
            };
        }(StatefulList::Elems<FooList, Unique>{});
    }
}

template <int N>
auto foo() -> decltype(void(StatefulList::PushBack<FooList, value_tag<N>>{}))
{
}

int main()
{
    if (false) // Не мешает.
    {
        foo<10>();
        foo<20>();
    }
    for (int x : FooElems())
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 10, 20
    foo<30>();
    for (int x : FooElems())
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 10, 20 - wrong! Cached from the previous call.
    struct UniqueType {};
    for (int x : FooElems<UniqueType>())
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 10, 20, 30 - correct
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно добиться такого эффекта с помощью статических полей шаблонного класса.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Registrator {
public:
    static const std::vector<int>& registered() {
        return reg();
    }
private:
    Registrator(int N) {
        reg().push_back(N);
    }
    static std::vector<int>& reg() {
        static std::vector<int> values;
        return values;
    }
    template<int N>
    friend class MyFunc;
};

template <int N>
struct MyFunc {
public:
    MyFunc() {
        (void)reg_;
    }
    void operator()() const {
        //Тело функции
        //...
        std::cout << N << '\n';
    };
private:
    static Registrator reg_;
};

template<int N>
Registrator MyFunc<N>::reg_ = {N};

template <int N>
MyFunc<N> func;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int n : Registrator::registered()) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    func<1>();
    func<2>();
    func<5>();
}
```